# MySql foreign Key error 1452 and database structure

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am by no means an expert in DB work and therefore please forgive anything that should seem obvious.

I have 3 tables that are related by foreign keys.
Tickets, Customer Contacts, and Customer Detail (see screenshots)

**Tickets Table:**
The tickets table has a foreign key on its contact ID field to the contact ID field in the customer Contacts table. There is also a foreign key on the customerID field back to the customerID field in the CustomerContacts table.

**Customer Contacts Table** 
The customer contacts table has a foreign key setup on is customer ID field back to the customer ID in the customer Detail table.

When I run this command:

```
INSERT INTO asinvdb.tickets (contactID, priorityID, categoryID,  subject,customerID) 
VALUES (74, 4, 4, 'Any random subject', (select customerID from     asinvdb.customerContacts where contactID = '74'));
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`asinvdb`.`tickets`, CONSTRAINT `customerIDtick` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`) REFERENCES `customerContacts` (`contactID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I have made sure that the customerID field in the customer contact record for contact 74 is populated (it has the customer ID of 124). I verified that there is a customer ID 124 in the customerDetails table.

I am trying to pull the value that already exists for this contact and put it in the ticket table. I want this value in there because I am going to want to search the tickets table by the customer and not just the contact. 
I have searched for a solution to this and every time I think I have it I get the same error.

Any help or direction pointing would be greatly appreciated and if there is more detail needed please let me know.

Thanks

Table information:

`customerDetail`

```
(PK)CustomerID INT(11)
CustomerName VARCHAR (45)
street1 VARCHAR (45)
street2 VARCHAR (45)
city VARCHAR (45)
state VARCHAR (45)
zip VARCHAR (45)
mainPhone VARCHAR (45)
mainFax VARCHAR (45)
companyWeb VARCHAR (45)
```

`customercontacts`

```
(PK)contactID Int (11)
FirstName VARCHAR (45)
lastName VARCHAR (45)
JobTitle VARCHAR (45)
email VARCHAR (45)
extension Int (6)
(FK) customerID
```

`tickets`

```
(PK) idTicket Int(11)
(FK) contactID Int(11)
(FK) priorityID Int(11)
(FK) categoryID Int(11)
(FK) statusID Int(11)
subject VARCHAR(45)
(FK) customerID Int(11)
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0GCm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHn1Q.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlgWm.png

Comment: If you need to add details, do so in your question, not as a comment. And do not add images, paste the relevant **text** as text in the question. This improves readability, searchability, persistence and access.

Comment: The error says that `tickets.customerID` is a foreign key to `customerContacts.contactID`. Shouldn't it be a FK to `customersDetails.customerID`?

Comment: @Barmar my initial thought in setting it up was to pull this data from the contact table to ensure I was pulling the proper customerID since it was already associated with the contact. Let me make a change to the FK and see if that works.

Comment: @Barmar that seems to have worked. I wasn't sure but thought having an FK reference an FK might have been the issue. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You didn't have a FK referencing a FK. It was referencing a PK, but it was the *wrong* PK.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key in the `tickets` table is not correct. The error message implies that you have:

```
FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customerContacts (contactID)
```

It should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (cusomerID) REFERENCES customerDetail (customerID)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was helpful.